# The square of any odd integer is odd.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics, proof-verification

Suppose that $n$ is an odd integer. Then $n = 2k + 1$ for some integer $k$.

Hence $n^2=(2k+1)(2k+1)=4k^2+4k+1=2(2k^2+2k)+1$.

Since $k$ is an integer, $2k^2 + 2k$ is an integer. Thus $n^2 = 2k' + 1$ for some integer $k'$.

Therefore $n^2$ is odd.

Is this correct?

Comment: Unclear what you're asking? Here is a proof, without any question.

Comment: Is this correct?

Comment: It's correct, but I have a *stylistic* objection: You reuse the letter $k$, which can be confusing to the reader. Better to use a different variable name, i.e., “Thus $n_2=2k'+1$ for some integer $k'$.”

Comment: Unless I'm reading this wrong your suggestion is the same as my example.

Comment: In your last statement, use $m$ instead of $k$: "Thus $n^2 = 2m + 1$ for some integer $m$".

Comment: Why? This would just replace all the k with m.

Comment: In order to emphasize the fact that it's not the same $k$ used in the first statement.

Comment: And thereby proving your statement without loss of generailty

Comment: A proof like "$(2k+1)^2=2(2k^2+2k)+1$" would be sufficient as it is obvious that the LHS is any odd number and the RHS is an odd number.

Answer (score 1):

you can write more generally that the product of 2 odd integers is odd

let $a = 2k+1$ and $b = 2p+1$

then $ab = (2k+1)(2p+1) = 2(2kp+k+p)+1 $ which is the general format of odd numbers

Comment: Yes but I wanted a proof that specifically dealt with squares if I could.

Comment: The same proof method easily generalizes the result, its worth noticing. Your proof is fine.

Comment: @SunshineTS Even more generally $\,(2k\!+\!1)n\,$ and $\,n\,$ have equal parity, since their difference is even, namely we have  $\,(2k\!+\!1)n -n = 2kn.\ $ Thus $\,2\mid (2k\!+\!1)n\iff 2\mid n\ \ $

Answer (score 0):

It's correct, but I would go a slightly different route. After proving that $n^2 = 4k^2 + 4k + 1$, I would say that $4k^2 + 4k$ is even, since $$\frac{4k^2 + 4k}{4} = k^2 + k$$ (we can even say that $4k^2 + 4k$ is doubly even). And when you add $1$ to an even number, you obtain an odd number.

Answer (score 0):

**Using modular arithmetic**:

$$n\equiv1\mod2\implies n^2\equiv1\mod2$$ because $n^2\bmod2=(n\bmod2)^2$ and $1^2=1$.

---

You can even handle the case of even and odd at the same time with

$$n\bmod2=(n\bmod2)^2=n^2\bmod2$$ because $0^2=0$ and $1^2=1$.